# Why do I get 404 on LAMP Permalinks (Using wordpress)

Tags: apache2, lamp, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been working on a website on an ubuntu server (amazone) and I get 404s entering pages.

I'll give all the information I can regarding the problem.

On WordPress

[image]

[image]

Refresh page:

[image]

I followed this tutorial:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/solved-permalinks-working-in-apache2-ubuntu-1010?replies=6

And nothing helped.

I found this post https://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalink-does-not-work-apart-from-default?replies=12 - so I entered 
I entered the file: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

and didn't find `AllowOverride None` to change to `AllowOverride All` So I added it myself here: 
[image]

Restarted apache, and I got an error. I refreshed the website, and found out it's not working..

*Undo `AllowOverride All` from `000-default.conf`*

What is the solution for this? 
I have never worked with Linux servers, so I'll need a very clear and well explained answer please.

BTW, This is what WP generates in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I have encountered the same

Comment: Suggest the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/wordpress.html) as a reference.

Answer (score 15):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Find this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
```

Change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

Then run:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Dont forget to restart apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: After days of research, this solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this answer - it saved me lots of nerves and time

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there exist an htaccess file in your WordPress home directory as shown above. If it is not there create one:

```
$ sudo nano /var/www/html/.htaccess
```

and copy paste the below to it

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule># END WordPress
```

Press ctrl+x and press y to save the file. And restart apache by

$ sudo service apache2 restart

You would want to tell apache to follow your .htaccess file. You can do this by editing the apache.conf file

```
$sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache.conf
```

Scroll down to the line 
By default it will be:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

change the value of AllowOverride to All so now it becomes:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Press ctrl+x and press y to save the configuration file. In order to make this changes to server first enable the mod_rewrite by.

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And then restart the server

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Done!

Source: https://www.wst.space/riddling-with-wordpress-permalink-setup-issues/